# knitr multiple plot alignment

Tags: r, knitr

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<fig.height=4,out.width=\textwidth,echo=FALSE>>=
plot(1,1)
plot(2,2)
@ 

\newpage
<<fig.height=4,out.width=\textwidth,echo=TRUE>>=
plot(1,1)
plot(2,2)
@ 

\end{document}
```

Note the screenshots below.
If `echo=FALSE`, horizontal alignment is off. The top plot is shifted to the right relative to the bottom plot.
If `echo=TRUE`, horizontal alignment is correct

[image: horizontal alignment is wrong]

[image: horizontal alignment is correct]

How would I fix the first example to align correctly with `echo=FALSE`?

Thank you!

Comment: sounds like a bug of a line feed somewhere; I will see. Next time you can report to https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues thanks!

Comment: I just checked it, and this is expected. Because the default value for the option `fig.align` is `'default'`, which means knitr will not do anything about the plots, and in the tex output you will see code like this: `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure/chunk1} \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure/chunk2}`, which caused the strange alignment in your case. This can be solved by setting the chunk option `fig.align='center'`. See http://yihui.name/knitr/options